# Mongodb: adding data without a field name possible?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I actually have two questions, but they both fall under the same idea, more or less:

1. Say I want to add a 'row' in MongoDB, is that possible at all by just using the order of the "fields"?

For example if I have my collection be

```
items = {
    { name: "John", age: "28" },
    { name: "Jake", age: "26" }
}
```

and I want to add `row = [ "Mike", "30" ]`, could I do `items.insertSpecial(row)` in some way so I don't have to fill in the "name" and "age"?

Currently, I am constructing a JSON object by going through the database fields manually like this:

```
insertRow() {
    var items = this.props.data;
    var query = {};

    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
        var textInput = "textInput" + i;
        var text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[textInput]).value.trim();
        query[items[i]] = text;
    }
    Meteor.call('items.insertRow', query);
}
```

where the method just does an `Items.insert(query);` but this seems awfully inefficient, depending on how many fields my database has!

I know theoretically mongo is unstructured, therefore I can't make assumptions about the structure... but is there no better way than creating my query using a for?

(additionally, if anyone can tell me a better way to get an array of the inputs entered in a form without using refs and ids that would be cool)

2. Similarly, or conversely, if I want to add a new "column" to the database, say `weight`, do I have to go through every row and add it?

I know `multi: true` is a possibility, but that adds the same value over and over, whereas I want to add say `w = ["200 lb", "234 lb"]` to the field `weight`, where `w` is formed from a series of inputs.

I was looking for something like:

```
Items.update({},
  { $unset: { [column]: w } },
  { multi: true });
```

that adds all items in array `w` sequentially to all items in the database. Does this exist or do I need to just do this in a for-loop?...

Currently I'm doing

```
insertColumn() {
    var items = this.props.data;
    var col = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.colName).value.trim();

    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
        var textInput = "textInput" + i;
        var text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[textInput]).value.trim();
        Meteor.call('items.insertColumn', col, { "id": items[i].id, "text": text });
    }
}
```

where the Meteor method is:

```
'items.insertColumn'(column, value) {
check(column, String);
check(value, Object);

Items.update(value.id, {
  $set: { [column]: [value.text] }
});
```

}

Any way of avoiding the call in the for and playing with IDs manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say I want to add a 'row' in MongoDB, is that possible at all by just
>   using the order of the "fields"?

No, not possible. One very good reason is that a dict is not ordered, in contrary with a list.

> Similarly, or conversely, if I want to add a new "column" to the
>   database, say weight, do I have to go through every row and add it?
>
> that adds all items in array w sequentially to all items in the
>   database. Does this exist or do I need to just do this in a
>   for-loop?...

Such a method does not exist, I am afraid you need to iterate over all documents and update each one by one *with the new value*